# Are telephone numbers still blocked?

Tags: discussion, support, spam

I just saw [a spam question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/664102) (10k +) with a telephone number in the title.

I wondered if there is still a block in place to detect phone numbers, or if that has since been removed.

Comment: The attempt to block spam by regexing on phone numbers has long since been dropped, IIRC. The specific spam run ended a while ago too.

Comment: On a side note: congrats on reaching 10k on Ask Ubuntu! :)